# Couldn't find package "collect-v8-age@^1.0.0" required by "@jest/reporters@^27.5.1" on the "npm" registry

Tags: reactjs, yarn-v2

Hi im trying to install libraries using yarn but I keep getting the error in the title:
error Couldn't find package "collect-v8-age@^1.0.0" required by "@jest/reporters@^27.5.1" on the "npm" registry.

Things i've tried:

```
npm install --global yarn
yarn cache clean --all
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Please help